# User-defined DistanceFunction for RegionNearest

Tags: version-10, computational-geometry

In the function `Nearest` , I can define my custom function using the `DistanceFunction` option. e.g:

```
dist[{u_, v_}, {x_, y_}] := 3 Abs[u - x] + 2 Abs[v - y]
```

Which I can use like this

```
Nearest[{ {1.5, .6}, {2, 0}, {1.25, 1.25}}, {0, 0}, DistanceFunction -> dist]
```

Is it possible to give a user-defined `DistanceFunction` for `RegionNearest` in **V10**? I don't see how to do this.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question at hand, hence a comment. With `Nearest` you can do this more efficiently if you use distance functions that are already "known". In this case you could transform by scaling the coordinates and use the Manhattan norm, as follows. `newpts = Map[{3, 2}*# &, origpts];
Nearest[newpts -> origpts, {0, 0}, 
 DistanceFunction -> "ManhattanDistance"]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to give `RegionNearest` a user defined `DistanceFunction`. I don't see an `Option` for this. However, you can define your own `RegionNearest` with custom distance function as follows:

```
dist[{u_, v_}, {x_, y_}] := Norm[{u, v} - {x, y}]
```

Then:

```
Clear[q1, q2];

regN[region_, point_] := NArgMin[{dist[point, {q1, q2}], {q1, q2} ∈ region}, {q1, q2}]
```

We can test that this works like the built-in `RegionNearest`:

```
RegionNearest[Disk[], {2, 3}] // N
```

> {0.554700196, 0.832050294}

```
regN[Disk[], {2, 3}]
```

> {0.55470039, 0.832050166}

Here is a more general definition that includes the `DistanceFunction` as a third argument and works for any dimension:

```
regN2[region_, point_, distanceF_] := NArgMin[{distanceF[point, x], x ∈ region}, x]
```

Here is an interesting distance function:

```
dist2[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] /; Length[x] == Length[y] := Total[((x - y) - 
                                                    1.2 Round[(x - y)/1.2])^2]
```

Then

```
regN2[Disk[], {2, 3}, dist2]  (* in 2D *)
```

> {-0.4, -0.6}

```
regN[Sphere[], {2, 3, 1}, dist2]  (* in 3D *)
```

> {0.784464204, 0.588348625, -0.196116827}

Of course you can define `distanceF` to be anything you want as long as it conforms to a distance definition.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is helpful. I was hoping there was a built-in way, but this is good enough. Hopefully in future updates, this will be added as an option.