# RegionNearest and neighborhoods

Tags: regions, mesh, computational-geometry, differential-geometry

In [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56424/user-defined-distancefunction-for-regionnearest) we see that `RegionNearest` isn't quite as 'capable' as `Nearest` for some things.

Similarly, I need to be able to find a given *neighborhood* of points on a `MeshRegion`. With just a set of vertices, one can easily use `Nearest` with the form `Nearest[p,{nDesired,radius}]`. Unfortunately, this does not work with `MeshRegion`, `RegionNearestFunction`, and friends. For example-

```
r = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[]];
v = MeshCoordinates[r];
p = v[[1]];
f = RegionNearest[r];

f[p]
(* {-0.156227, 0.987698, 0.00678839} *)

f[p, {10, 0.1}]
(* RegionNearestFunction::argx: RegionNearestFunction [...] called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected *)
```

Obviously, I can use `Nearest[]` on the mesh coordinates and get an answer -

```
ff = Nearest[v];
ff[p, {10, 0.5}]
(* {{-0.156227, 0.987698, 0.00678839}, {-0.232192, ... *)
```

*But* this doesn't take advantage of the graph-connectivity in the MeshRegion data structure. The meshes that I deal with are much more complicated than a simple sphere here, so the `Norm[p-q]` method it uses in this case gives bad values when there are 'creases' or 'folds' in the surface.

It would seem that getting the n-Ring neighbors of a point *p* on a MeshRegion should be a pretty straight forward thing (I have plenty of code that does this for `GraphicsComplex` style data) and maybe even something that *should* be built in, but I can't quite figure out how to do it (or traverse a `MeshRegion` as if it were a `Graph` for what that's worth.) Does anyone have a suggestion for how to take advantage of the new `...Region` features for this sort of thing?

(n.b.- more specifically, I need this information to compute the differential geometry at all discrete *v* in *r* or, even better, an interpolation for any point in *r*. I've been playing with some of the new Computational Geometry features but can't quite figure out how to do this on MeshRegions. I again have some code that turns meshes into nonuniform-interpolated functions that I can play with this way, but, again, would like to find a way to do, say, `ArcCurvature`, `FrenetSetretSystem` sort of things on **surfaces** instead of just lines. See [this mercifully closed question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78094/differential-geometry-on-a-meshregion?s=1|2.4187) of mine for related angst.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't mind using undocumented stuff, you can access lots of useful properties by converting the `BoundaryMeshRegion` to a `MeshObject`. In this case "VertexVertexConnectivityRules" is useful. Here I start at vertex 1 and go up to 4 steps out along the mesh edges:

```
r = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[]];

vvcr = Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject[r]["VertexVertexConnectivityRules"];

q = Union@Flatten@NestList[ReplaceAll[vvcr], {1}, 4];

HighlightMesh[r, {0, q}, MeshCellShapeFunction -> (Sphere[#, .03] &)]
```

[image]

Alternatively, to get the connectivity graph you could extract the edges with `MeshCells`:

```
g = Graph[MeshCells[r, 1] /. Line[{x__}] :> UndirectedEdge[x]];
```

Then use standard graph functions

```
HighlightGraph[g, NeighborhoodGraph[g, 1, 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution,But if we just want to highlight the boundry [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gfeJV.png).Do you have same method?

Comment: Thanks @simon-woods ! It's almost as if there should be a Wiki somewhere with the undocumented stuff 'documented' :)

Comment: That would be nice - I've lost count of the number of times I've coded something from scratch only to discover it was already implemented in some obscure context. Hopefully some future version will give access to all these internal mesh properties through a documented interface.

Comment: @yode, I guess you could take the complement of the n radius neighborhood and the (n-1) radius neighborhood to get just the boundary vertices.

Comment: *Now* all of the r["Properties"] make sense! For the 'higher level' BMO, none of them do anything meaningful, but after `ToMeshObject` they do. For what its worth, this is a (much more complete) version of what I was storing / computing on in all my pre-MeshRegion stuff.